# Android Reusing activities with different data

Tags: java, android

Hi I'm developing an android application and have two activities that are practically the same, but load different data. I currently have two Activities with a lot of duplicate code and I feel I can optimise it by using only one activity.

**Activity 1:**

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.right_hearing_test);

    String topHtml = this.getString(R.string.top_content);
    String bottomHtml = this.getString(R.string.bottom_content);

    View infoButton = findViewById(R.id.info_button);
    infoButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    TextView titleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_text);
    titleText.setText(R.string.Hearing_Test);

    mScrollButton = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);

    topContent = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.top_content);
    topContent.setBackgroundColor(0);

    bottomContent = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_content);
    bottomContent.setBackgroundColor(0);

    activityHelper = new ActivityHelper(this);

    topContent.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/" + topHtml);
    bottomContent.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/" + bottomHtml);

    getScreenSize();
    getMargins();

    setResult(RESULT_OK);
}
```

**Activity 2**

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.left_hearing_test);

    View infoButton = findViewById(R.id.info_button);
    infoButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    mScrollButton = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);

    topContent = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.top_content);
    topContent.setBackgroundColor(0);

    bottomContent = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_content);
    bottomContent.setBackgroundColor(0);

    String topHtml = this.getString(R.string.switch_file);
    String bottomHtml = this.getString(R.string.bottom_content);

    activityHelper = new ActivityHelper(this);

    topContent.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/" + topHtml);
    bottomContent.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/" + bottomHtml);

    getScreenSize();
    getMargins();
}
```

I Load certain data into the web views and the button in activity 1, then the user does a test, which then take the user to activity 2. Here all it does is display different data in the web views and the button.

My question is if I reuse one activity for both pages, how do I load the correct data into each one and is it even possible?

I've used a helper class for a lot of other methods I use on both activities by passing the context in, but I would like to use only one activity for the different content I display in the webviews and the button!

Thanks for any input!

Comment: apparently only the `setContentView` is different? you need to start by identifying when you need to display one or the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply keep a flag to decide which option to chose..
Bellow will give you an idea how to control it.

You can control this flag unisg getStringExtra(), putStringExtra()
For example. you will start your activity from FromActivity class.

FromActivity.java

```
.......    
Intent i = new Intent(FromActivity.this,YourActivity.class);
i.putExtra("Flag","optionone");
startActivity(i);
.......
```

or

```
..
Intent i = new Intent(FromActivity.this,YourActivity.class);
i.putExtra("Flag","optiontwo");
startActivity(i);
...
```

YourActivity.java

```
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ......
        ..
        ..
        String flag = String.valueOf(getIntent().getStringExtra("Flag"));

        if(flag.equalsIgnoreCase("optionone")){

            String topHtml = this.getString(R.string.top_content);
            String bottomHtml = this.getString(R.string.bottom_content);

            TextView titleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_text);
            titleText.setText(R.string.Hearing_Test);


        }else if(flag.equalsIgnoreCase("optiontwo")){
            String topHtml = this.getString(R.string.top_content);
            String bottomHtml = this.getString(R.string.bottom_content);
        }else{
    }
        .....
        ...
        ...
        if(flag.equalsIgnoreCase("optionone")){
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
        }
        ....
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, I'll implement it not! Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks for your appreciation. If these were helpful to you, can you please select this answer as accepted one :)

Answer (score 1):

1) You can put most of the common data in one BaseActivity and then make two  activities extending it. And then load data in individual activities as per your requirement.

Comment: you see I do that by using a java helper. Can I not use one activity, and find out once the test has been done?

Comment: Other solution would be two use Action in Intent. You can set different action for the different task that you want to perform with the same activity. And do stuff.

So if u are starting activity to do 1 operation then while starting activity set an action in Intent with string like "Action1".
When your activity starts you can check what action you have set and do the operation 1

Similarly when you are starting activity to do operation 2 then set action "Action2" in Intent, and when your activity has started you can check for the action and perform operation 2

Comment: So I use an intent to get to activity 1, do I pass in an action when I open that activity? Then in the test activity (Which is after activity 1) once that's complete and I use an intent to open activity 2, I pass in another action? then in the shared activity, I do an `if` statement looking for that action string?

Comment: From the Activity you are starting the activity in question you will set different actions for the different operation you want to perform. And in your activity in question you will check in if for the different action and perform operation accordingly.  Please use coding convention for naming the actions.